# Ajax.Beginform is submitting only once mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hello i am creating an advance search form where an Ajax.Beginform is called from jquery with the .submit() event, the Ajax.Beginform returns a partialView and update a div on the page. Now when i press the search button the first time everything works fine and the page is updated properly but when i try to press it again the the form is never submitted and controller action is never called. When i checked firebug i found this error showing in the console every time i press the search button:

```
    TypeError: $.validator.methods[method] is undefined


    result = $.validator.methods[ method ].call( this, val, element, rule.parameters...
```

And this is my code:

The ajax beginfirm from the View:

```
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AdvancedSearch", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "searchResults", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { id = "advancedSearchForm"}))
```

The jquery function:

```
function submitAdvancedSearch() {    
    if ($("#Name").val().trim() == "" && $("#LastName").val().trim() == "" && $("#Company").val().trim() == "" ) {
            $("#resultError").text("Enter at least one search criteria");
    }
    else {
         $("#resultError").text("");
         $("#advancedSearchForm").submit();
         $("#advancedClientsSearch").prop("hidden", false);
    }
}
```

And this is the Button:

```
    <input type="button" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitAdvancedSearch()" />
```

This is my bundle packages:

```
                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js",
                    "~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js",
                    "~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"));

                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

NB: i am using MVC5 and jQuery JavaScript Library v2.1.3

Comment: If your using `Ajax.BeginForm()`, what is the point of the script? Make the button `type="submit" and delete your script.

Comment: no this code is truncated i do some fields check before submitting the form.

Comment: Then show your real code.

Comment: I just updated the function

Comment: You need to use the `OnBegin` option to call a function and return `false` if you want to cancel the form submission. [Refer example here](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-use-onbegin-method-with-ajax-beginform/)

Comment: no i dont want to cancel it i want to be able to call it over and over again and updating the page with the proper results. Now i am able to call it once but if to try to call it again nothing happens until i reload the page.

Comment: What do you mean. You function does not do do anything except display a message if the criteria is not met (you never hit the `$("#advancedSearchForm").submit();` line.

Comment: i am using an if else so when one of the fields has some characters in it the else section will enter and the $("#advancedSearchForm").submit(); is hit. as i said it is working just fine the first time but my problem is when i try to call it a second third ....

Comment: It's not working fine. If your condition is met (hits the `else` block) then you call `.submit()` and do a normal submit. What is the point of the `Ajax.BeginForm()`? (or `$("#advancedClientsSearch").prop("hidden", false);` since you have already left the page?)

Comment: i am not leaving the page if you check my question i already said that i am returning a partialview and in the Aja.beginform i am using the UpdateTargetId = "searchResults" to update the div on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found out what it was i had set some validation rules that are affecting the functionality once i removed them everything works fine now

```
        $("#ClientName").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    messages: {
        required: "Client Name can not be empty."
    }
});

$("#ClientLastName").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    messages: {
        required: "Client Last Name can not be empty."
    }
});

$("#ClientCompanyName").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    messages: {
        required: "Company Name can not be empty."
    }
});
```

i use them for another page but MVC uses default naming so i had a kind of conflict.

Comment: that's what I thought ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you not need auto validation then remove "~/bundles/jqueryval" bundle.

Comment: i am using the auto validation on other pages. but i include them on the master page so i wont have to include them on every page